# How can I make Ubuntu recognize RAM?

Tags: ram, memory-test

I added RAM to my PC with Ubuntu 18.04 but it does not finish booting the system.
I added two memories of 2GB each, before had a module of two cards of 1 Gb each. Check the Acer instructions and the ones you buy are compatible.
The notebook is Acer Extensa 5620z Intel Pentium 1.46 GHz 533 MHz
2 GB DDR2.

It does not give any error, because it would sound the beep, but it does not start the system, it passes the Ubuntu logo as always when loading, but it does not start, it keeps the screen with the ubuntu logo (the word ubuntu and the five red dots underneath).

Is there any way to make it recognize the new memory, doing it from the BIOS or in safe boot of Ubuntu?

Thank you.

**Edit**:

I did more tests and the modules are compatible with the laptop.

I explain: I had a module of two pieces of 1 GB each. I put the new module of 2 pieces of 2 Gb each. And it did not start.
Now I put one of those that had first 1 GB and one of the new 2 GB, and boots perfectly, recognizing the 2.92 Gb.
Which means it works.
How can I do to accept both 2 GB?

Comment: How much RAM did it have before you added 2GB? How much does it have now? Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1063578/edit) the question and provide your system specification?

Comment: You don't. It is the hardware's task to provide it to the OS. You need to make sure you inserted the correct memory module. This sounds as you have the wrong modules. 1 thing to check: what does the bios say about it?

Comment: Second thing to do: Run memtest68+ (available from the GRUB menu) to check the RAM for errors.

Comment: @dessert memtest86 should be run only if the hardware recognizes the RAM.  As Rinzwind said, it's the hardware's job to report it, so checking if the system actually recognizes it is the first step.

Comment: How should I proceed to check what you say to me, I do not have much practice with Ubuntu or dealing with errors of this type.
Thank you.

Comment: Open BIOS and look what it says there at the memory info. That is step 1. If there the modules are not recognized you need to either get correct memory modules OR check how they are inserted in the slots. If you do see the correct  amount of modules and memory sizes then memtest is the next option. But we do that after step 1 ;) Regarding the edit: put in the 1 and the OTHER 2 ... does it still work? If so good! otherwise the 2nd one might be broken,

Comment: I hope when you chose to replace the ram, that you got rid of any static electricity and also discharged any static electricity by pressing the power button after everything has been unplugged, is the ram facing the right way and locked into place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an Ubuntu issue, it's a hardware issue.

The BIOS of this 2008 vintage machine has a ceiling on the amount of RAM it will recognize, baked in when designed. [It was designed for a maximum of two each 1GB memory modules](https://www.cnet.com/products/acer-extensa-5620z-1a2g16mi-15-4-p-t2310-vista-home-premium-2-gb-ram-160-gb-hdd-series/specs/), and if you can get it to see a 2GB memory module, count your blessings. [You are not the first user](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/311218/4gb-ram-fuer-extensa-5620z) to find they can get to 3GB, but not 4GB, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks @K7AAY, I'm still doing tests without result, if you do not see another better idea, I'll give you a good answer.
Although I have to say that in the Acer documentation, it says it supports the 4 Gb module as long as the laptop is 64-bit x64                                                                 https://icecat.es/p/acer/lx.e980x.028/noutbuci-Extensa+5620Z-1A2G16Mi-1325458.html

Comment: Well, there's what Acer documents, and then there's what the engineers wrote into the BIOS...